# Laravel 5 route not resolving

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

I cannot get the named routes to resolve in my controllers. I am very new to Laravel so I am sure I missed something obvious. Any help is appreciated.

I have the following code in *routes.php*:

```
Route::get('password/email', ['uses' => 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail', 'as', 'session.getEmail']);
```

Then in one of the Controllers I want to extract the route and place it in a variable I am passing to a blade template like this:

```
$forgot_password_link = route('session.getEmail');
return view('auth.login', compact('logo', 'forgot_password_link'));
```

This is then used in the form like this:

```
<a href="{{ $forgot_password_link }} class="left">Forgot Your Password?</a>
```

But I get the following error when I load the page:

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 278:
>   Route [session.getEmail] not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'as', 'session.getEmail'
```

this should be key=>value pair